# How to manipulate nodes coming from a $.get request?

Tags: jquery

I'm doing a $.get() request which returns some HTML.
I would like to manipulate that html before I'm adding it to the DOM (make it hidden).

Can I do this without adding it to a behind-the-scene node, manipulate it and finally add it to the destination node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
newHtml = $.get();
wrappedSet = $(newHtml);
```

You now have a wrapped set of your new html, which you can manipulate using standard jQuery methods.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just mean $(newHtml)?

Comment: yes, indeed. I changed the syntax without the quotes and it works exactly as I wanted. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you can:

```
$.get(url, function(html) {
    var $myDOMObjects = $(html);

    // manipulate to your heart's content

    $('body').append($myDomObjects);
});
```